# Как изменить папку по умолчанию в Денвере?

Tags: apache, denwer, php

В Денвере при создании сайта создается папка с названием сайта и в ней должна быть папка www. Так вот я хочу изменить название этой папки на свое. То есть например вместо:

```
home/mysite.ru/www/index.php
```

вот это:

```
home/mysite.ru/root/index.php
```

Я подозреваю, что что-то надо прописать в настройках апача, но что именно не знаю.

Comment: что вам действительно поможет так это не думать о денвере как об отдельной программе, а думать как о apache/php и прочих компонентах, зачем усложнять себе жизнь новой сущностью ? вот по вашему вопросу - есть же httpd.apache.org там все написано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Откройте файл C:\WebServers\usr\local\apache\conf\vhosts.conf
2. Найдите сверху строку "# Host /home/test1.ru/www"
3. Начинайте с нее и очень внимательно следуйте указаниям из комментариев в самом файле.
4. Не забывайте перезапускать сервер каждый раз, когда захотите увидеть изменения.

Comment: там сказано, что после перезапуска денвера изменения в этом файле потеряются

Comment: Правильно. Я потому не написал, что его надо редактировать, но написал "внимательно читать" :) По примеру в vhosts.conf для /home/test1.ru/www применить в httpd.conf.
Это чтобы понимать, что такое Virtual Host.

Это уже из httpd.conf

\# Следующая директива необходима для того, чтобы подключить файл со всеми
\# виртуальными хостами, доступными в системе. Этот файл модифицируется 
\# автоматически при запуске, поэтому любые внесенные в него изменения
\# не сохраняются. Если вы хотите повлиять на содержимое файла, то измените
\# шаблон виртуального хоста, идущий выше.
\#
Include conf/vhosts.con

Comment: Премного благодарен!

Comment: кстати можно обойтись без изменения. Я щас понял что можно еще вот так заходить по нужной директории root.mysite.ru

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста.
P.S. - root.mysite.ru - это конфигурация поддомена. Вопрос был как сделать так, чтобы корневой директорией для именно test1.ru была бы root вместо www. В вашем случае root уже - корневая для root.mysite.ru. В этом разница.